# Purchasing of chosen type of the product

Tags: javascript, php, web

I’m working on online-shop. I have two types of the one product which differ just in color. After the User chose one of the variants he precedes to payment. How my web-site should understand which exactly type of the product (color) the Users wants to purchase?

I do not have a code right now. Just seeking for general advise what to start learning from? What is a general approach?  As I see it right now: there should be a selector. When User choose the variant the code determines which exactly product is it.
I am a beginner, so understand that my explanation could be not clear

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Nikita, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details about your problems. Things you have tried and didn't work.  Please review [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a general question, so I am not sure if I am not missed the point.

Probably it would be easier if you will explain what action you expect after customer has chosen the desired color and before the payment.

First idea: Before user precedes to payment user should fill the form and select field which tells what color he wants (the list of available color should be predefined in the form so that the user won't choose something that is not exist).

Then this information is stored in your database and further used by you to complete the order.